# Why are signed applets more "secure"? Are unsigned applets dead?

Tags: java, security, applet

With Oracle's [latest Java update](http://java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml) they finally removed the ability of unsigned applets to run without requiring the user to perform manual settings changes (such as adding the website to an exception list).  Since mucking about with security settings in the Java Control Panel is beyond the average end user, this effectively kills the use of unsigned applets on the web.

How did we get here?  I always considered **unsigned** applets to be the safe variety and signed applets to be scary.  Signed applets can see my file system; unsigned applets run in a sandbox, right?  I specifically made my applet unsigned so that the end user would feel secure in knowing my app cannot see or act on their file system.  Now that idea seems dead.

Is there a way to run an unsigned applet without requiring the user perform manual settings changes?

Comment: Unsigned applets don't have a confirmed source and there will always be loopholes through which the system resources may be accessed.

Comment: But, arguably, it is *applets* as a whole that seem dead to me. Long dead. JavaScript won that battle over a decade ago.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So sandboxing is an inherently flawed concept?

Comment: Yes because it can never be truly bulletproof. The same pattern repeats itself everywhere.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Applets are dead and JavaScript won.  No arguments there.  My question only concerns the last vestiges of the use of applets before they die off completely...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik js won the battle but still a lot of things you cant do with JS and need to complement with an applet.

Comment: In recent times, a *signed* applet can still be sand-boxed.  If it is, the security warnings are more mild.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason behind the move is the lack of trust in the sandbox security due to recent exploits found, and that now a little 'extra' is exiged in the form of a trusted certificate - it's as dumb as saying 'hey, it will break the sandbox anyway, so let's have it signed at least'

I don't say it is taking decisions like this out of fear is right... but I think it is what we must cope with